# Composition of mulitvariable functions with different dimensions

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I have $\gamma : (0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}^3\backslash\{0\}, \gamma (t) :=\begin{pmatrix} -t\\t \\ t^2 \end{pmatrix}$ and $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \backslash \{0\} \to \mathbb{R}^2, f(x)=\begin{pmatrix} \sin |x|_2 \\ |x|_2^3+1 \end{pmatrix}$. What is $f \circ \gamma : (0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}^2$? I thought I could just add a $0$ to $f(x)=\begin{pmatrix} \sin |x|_2 \\ |x|_2^3+1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and exchange the variables component-wise, but I guess this doesn't work out, since the output of $f\circ \gamma$ has to be two-dimensional.

Comment: typo in the first sentence

Comment: Thank you, edited.

Answer (score 1):

You want to think of $\gamma (t)$ as $x.$ Thus

$$(f\circ \gamma) (t) =f(\gamma (t))= (\sin |\gamma (t)|, |\gamma (t)|^3+1).$$

Now note $|\gamma (t)|= (t^2 + t^2 + t^4)^{1/2}.$

Comment: Is $$(f\circ \gamma)'(1)=\begin{pmatrix} \sin(3)\\ 3\sqrt{3}\end{pmatrix}$$ correct?